# Dropna isn't dropping, fillna isn't filling and my list comprehension can't comprehend how to get rid of nans (python)

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a case where I am adding data from one dataframe to another, but I can't rid of the nan values.

Example data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'Journal' : ['US Drug standards.','Acta veterinariae.','Bulletin of big toe science.','The UK journal of dermatology.'],
        'ISSN_1': ['0096-0225', '0567-8315','0007-4977','0007-0963'],
        'ISSN_2': ['0096-0225','nan','0007-4977','0007-0963'],
        'ISSN_3': ['nan','1820-7448','nan','0366-077X'],
        'ISSN_4': ['nan','0567-8315','nan','1365-2133']
        }
        )

df1 = df1[['Journal'] + df1.columns[:-1].tolist()]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'Full Journal Title': ['Drug standards.','Acta veterinaria.','Bulletin of marine science.','The British journal of dermatology.'],
    'Abbreviated Title': ['DStan','Avet','Marsci','BritSkin'],
    'Total Cites': ['223','444','324','166'],
    'ISSN': ['0096-0225','0567-8315','0007-4977','0007-0963']                           
     })

#this makes list of ISSNs from df1 to combine into a column to add to df2
xx=df1.set_index('Journal').values.tolist() 
df2['New']=df2.ISSN.apply(lambda x : [y for y in xx if x in y] )
df2=df2[df2.New.apply(len)>0]
df2['New']=df2.New.apply(pd.Series)[0].apply(lambda x : ','.join(x))
```

I have tried a replace:
    df2 = df2.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

I have tried dropna:
    print(df2.dropna(subset=['New']))

I have tried fillna:
    print(df2.fillna(''))

I have tried a replace list comprehension:
    xx = [value for value in xx if str(value) != 'nan']

No matter what I try, the "New" column is still full of nans.

```
0                0096-0225,0096-0225,nan,nan
1          0567-8315,nan,1820-7448,0567-8315
2                0007-4977,0007-4977,nan,nan
3    0007-0963,0007-0963,0366-077X,1365-2133
```

I want them skipped or dropped. I only want the valid ISSNs.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The nans that are in you data frame are strings, not null values i.e. `'nan'` versus `np.nan` So the typical operations dealing with`nan` is not recognizing them. Try `df2 = df2.replace('nan', '')`

Comment: The question is: Why would you create 'nan' in the first place? They normally appear when dealing with empty data or running operations

Comment: @Anton vBR I created them for the example. I am importing a file in Excel that has missing cells that appear as 'nan'

Comment: then use **df1.to_dict()** and share that data instead

Comment: I worked from the original excel file and used ".to_dict()". Here is the result:
`{'ISSN_2': {0: '0096-0225', 1: '0567-8315', 2: '0007-4977', 3: '0007-0963'}, 'Journal': {0: 'US Drug standards.', 1: 'Acta veterinariae.', 2: 'Bulletin of big toe science.', 3: 'The UK journal of dermatology.'}, 'ISSN_1': {0: '0096-0225', 1: '0567-8315', 2: '0007-4977', 3: '0007-0963'}, 'ISSN_4': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: '1365-2133'}, 'ISSN_3': {0: nan, 1: '1820-7448', 2: nan, 3: '0366-077X'}}`

Comment: Ok, solved it. I was working on the second dataframe after the data had been moved over. `df1 = df1.dropna()` eliminated the nans, so I was trying to solve the problem on the wrong dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. The first is that the question shows that `'nan'` is in the dataframe, however the comment suggests that this should actually be `nan` (string versus null).

The second is that you are storing lists, and then strings of those lists in a dataframe which is typically discouraged - for precisely the reason you are running into - there is often unexpected behavior.

I will address the question as it was posed although you should be able to adapt this to `nans` as well

The code that is causing the issue is:

```
xx=df1.set_index('Journal').values.tolist() 
df2['New']=df2.ISSN.apply(lambda x : [y for y in xx if x in y] )
df2=df2[df2.New.apply(len)>0]
df2['New']=df2.New.apply(pd.Series)[0].apply(lambda x : ','.join(x))
```

The second line here is adding *all* of the values in `xx` to `df2['New']` which contains `'nan'` then subsequent lines turn these into a list and then a string. Once those values exist in a string or list you are not going to be able access them with normal pandas methods.

My suggestion would be to remove them from xx and then they won't show up in `df2` at all:

```
xx=df1.set_index('Journal').values.tolist()
#get rid of nans here
xx=[[y for y in x if y != 'nan'] for x in xx]
df2['New']=df2.ISSN.apply(lambda x : [y for y in xx if x in y] )
df2=df2[df2.New.apply(len)>0]
df2['New']=df2.New.apply(pd.Series)[0].apply(lambda x : ','.join(x))
```

Note the second line here is removing the `'nan'`s at time when they are easily accessible.

This should get you what you need, though once again I would caution against storing lists in dataframes if possible and be sure to use `nan` and not `'nan'`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I think `[y for y in x if y != 'nan']` is what I have been trying to get to but I'm learning list comprehensions. I took this code from a set that didn't have blank values in the table, but applied it to new data that has blank values.