# Pandas data frame removing rows with 'nan' by column name

Tags: python, pandas

After reading excel via pandas `read_excel` end up with rows with that has type string 'nan'. I tried to drop them using all the available method discussed here but seems like it doesn't work:

Here are the attempts:

`df.dropna(subset=['A'], inplace=True)`

I thought this would work, it reduced the number of rows from the data frame without removing rows that has `'nan'`

`df = df[df.A.str.match('nan') == False]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropna isn't dropping, fillna isn't filling and my list comprehension can't comprehend how to get rid of nans (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610007/dropna-isnt-dropping-fillna-isnt-filling-and-my-list-comprehension-cant-comp)

Answer (score 1):

We can `replace` 'nan' first then use `dropna`

```
df.replace({'A':{'nan':np.nan}}).dropna(subset=['A'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way of doing it is by boolean indexing since they are strings i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['nan',1,2,3],'B':[1,2,3,'nan']})

# To remove 'nan's from only A
print(df[(df.A!='nan')])

#   A    B
#1  1    2
#2  2    3
#3  3  nan


#For removing all the rows that hold `nan`
print(df[(df!='nan').all(1)])
#   A  B
#1  1  2
#2  2  3
```

Comment: This will remove regardless the column, need to remove only if coulumn A has them

Comment: Then you can go for the first option I posted